# Every measure on a discrete space is $\Sigma$-finite?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I was trying to solve the exercise of the book "E. Cinlar - Probability and Stochastics" on page 18, No. 3.13 (c) but on the second part I lack ideas.

EX.  Let $E$ be a countable set and $\mathcal{E}=2^E$. Show that every measure, $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal{E})$ is $\Sigma$-finite, i.e. there is a sequence $(\mu_n)_n$ of measures on $(E,\mathcal{E})$ such that $\mu=\sum_{n}\mu_{n}$ and every $\mu_{n}$ is finite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the example that this exercise refers to, any measure $\mu$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$ can be represented as
$$ \mu=\sum_{x\in E}m(x)\delta_x,$$
where $\delta_x$ is the Dirac-measure in $x$ and $m(x):=\mu(\{x\})\in[0,\infty]$ for all $x\in E$. You can write
$$ \mu=\sum_{x\in E \,: \,m(x)<\infty}m(x)\delta_x+ \sum_{x\in E \,: \,m(x)=\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \delta_x\right),$$
where there are countably many summands in total and each of them is a finite measure.

Comment: I think you are supposed to consider $x \in D$ for your summations, not $x \in E$. (Thanks for the useful answer, too.)

Comment: @Novice What's $D$?

Comment: In the book that was being discussed (Probability and Stochastics), $D$ is a countable subset of $E$, and the discrete measure is defined to be $\mu(A) = \sum_{x \in D} m(x) \, \delta_x(A)$ for $A \in \mathscr{E}$.

Comment: @Novice That may be the notation in the book, but my answer uses the notation from the question as asked by the OP.